# Appending a column in a csv file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I was having some trouble with csv files. I would like to add a new column, that being a multiplication of the previous one. For instance `['price', 'pricex2'] [[2,4],[6,12]]` and so on, how could I do that?

I also happen to have € signs at the end of every number in the price column, but I think I can tackle that by taking the float for the 4 first characters right? For example `price = 2,45€         numericalPrice = float(price[0:3])`.

I would rather not use pandas as it gives me trouble when installing.

Comment: Are you using another package other than pandas?

Comment: Can't you just multiply it by two when you use the file? Storing 'this number multiplied by a constant' doesn't seem to add any information...

Comment: What part of doing the CSV transformation are you struggling with?  Do you know how to read a CSV file, write to a CSV file? etc.?  I think once you've tried to do that you should come back with your code if it doesn't work and ask a specific question.

Comment: As I'm a newbie and never used panda, I have this code writen down modified from https://www.kite.com/python/answers/how-to-add-a-column-to-a-csv-file-in-python

Comment: def priceConverter(file,multiplyer):
    df = pd.read_csv(csvfile)
    df["Modified price"] = float(df["Jewerly_name_price"])[0:3]*multiplyer
    df.to_csv(csvfile, index=False)

priceConverter(csvfile,2)

Comment: but again, no idea of what im doing

Comment: I just learned today the basics of managing csv files

Answer (score 1):

I'll answer the second part of the question, because your suggestion is dangerous.  If the price is not exactly 4 characters long it fails.  You should do:

```
price = "2,45€"
numericalprice = float(price[:-1])
print(numericalprice)
```